# Relacionamento de entidades C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor-pages

Estou precisando trazer dados para uma razor page. tenho duas tabelas no banco, uma chamada residencias e outra visitresidencias(que registra todas as visitas que fizeram a uma residencia).

Como posso trazer o count de visitas em uma razor page tipada com a model de residencias?

Model residencia:

```
public class Residencia
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Título")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Valor")]
        [Required]
        public decimal Value { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Imagem")]
        public string Image { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Instagram Url")]
        public string InstagramUrl { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Slug")]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Slug muito grande")]
        public string Slug { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<VisitResidencia> VisitResidencias { get; set; }
    }
```

Model VisitResidencia:

```
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }

public int ResidenciaId { get; set; }

public DateTime Data { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

public virtual Residencia Residencia { get; set; }
```

Razor page:

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-2">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-4">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VisitResidencias)
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary"}) |
                    <input id="Delete" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"value="Delete" onclick="deleteitem(@item.Id)"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: `var total = Model.Count()` ?

Comment: Valeu, estava tentando colocar o count no model . item, mas utilizei sua ideia de declarar uma variável total e deu certo.                                                                   
var total = item.VisitResidencias.Where(x => x.ResidenciaId == item.Id).Count();         e coloquei um include no controller pra trazer as duas tabelas

Comment: boa, pode tbm fazer uma ViewModel específica já com essas propriedades, fica até mais "elegante" :)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize isso:

```
@Html.Display(modelItem => item.VisitResidencias.Count())
```

Se aparecer sempre 0 (zero) pode ser que falte o .Include(c=>c.VisitResidencias) na consulta ou o mapeamento esteja errado.

Answer (score -1):

Referenciaste o @model "Teuprojeto".model.VisitResidencia no inicio? acho que depois podias até fazer uma lamda expression e ir buscar o que quer que fosse ao modelo que pretendias!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).